# Installing aws cli using pip in Docker file

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, aws-cli

I am getting this error while trying to install aws cli from pip.

```
ERROR: Service 'remote_host' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py &&     python3 get-pip.py &&     pip3 install awscli --upgrade' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

**Docker File**:

```
FROM centos
RUN yum -y install openssh-server
RUN useradd remote_user && \
    echo remote_user:1234 | chpasswd && \
    mkdir /home/remote_user/.ssh && \
    chmod 700 /home/remote_user/.ssh
COPY remote-key.pub /home/remote_user/.ssh/authorized_keys
RUN chown remote_user:remote_user -R /home/remote_user/.ssh && \
    chmod 600 /home/remote_user/.ssh/authorized_keys
RUN /usr/bin/ssh-keygen -A
EXPOSE 22
RUN rm -rf /run/nologin

RUN yum -y install mysql
RUN curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py && \
    python3 get-pip.py && \
    pip3 install awscli --upgrade
 
CMD /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

**Issue** This is my Docker file and I'm getting error by this. can someone help me with this. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seems you don't have `python3` nor `python3-pip` in your image. You can rectify the issue by installing it.

Instead of:

```
RUN yum -y install mysql
```

you can write:

```
RUN yum -y install mysql python3 python3-pip
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of installing Python3, I recommend using Python2.7 and updating the URL.(This is for learning purpose not for production environment)

You can refer updated URL using below-attached artifact,

```
RUN curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py && \
python get-pip.py && \
pip install awscli --upgrade
```

Comment: Python 2.7 is no longer supported, and probably has a number of security issues outstanding nowadays. This is terrible advice.